# Inconsistent project encoding in IntelliJ and Gradle - wrong national characters in app output

Tags: java, encoding, intellij-idea, gradle

I wrote a Java web application that gets a Youtube movie title and sends it to the client. I receive the title from the Internet using the link `http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" + movieUrl + "&format=xml` (e.g. http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvCtDwoCqGM&format=xml). The string with XML tags goes to my app. There I extract the title and send it to the client.

I use IntelliJ and Gradle. The project encoding was initially set to windows-1250 but I changed it to UTF-8 (**File -> Settings -> Files encoding** or similar). When I run the app via 'Run' button in IntelliJ (it uses JDK_directory\bin\java to launch the app), the returned result is correct and looks as it should:

```
"video_title":"Na tym obrazie jest coś więcej. Kolejna tajemnica Mona Lisy"
```

but when I run the same app via Gradle task (gradle build and gradle run), the result is:

```
"video_title":"Na tym obrazie jest coĹ› wiÄ™cej. Kolejna tajemnica Mona Lisy"
```

(Polish characters are incorrect; the same happends with other languages, e.g. letters with 'Umlaut' in German). Btw. IntelliJ is configured the way that it runs Gradle build task when it makes the project. It is very confusing and uncomfortable. I inserted

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
```

and

```
[ compileJava, compileTestJava ]*.options*.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

and

```
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options.collect {options -> options.encoding = 'UTF-8'}
```

into build.script file but nothing helped me.

I wonder what is the reason of this difference. It is possible to make Gradle 'forget' old encoding and 'get focused' on the new one :) ? Maybe it would be helpful to create the project once again (this time with correct encoding from the very beginning) and copy Java and Gradle code from the old project to the new one?

EDIT: Earlier I was extracting the title from the JSON object that I got from YT (I changed `format` parameter to `json`) but Polish letters were presented as `\uXXXX`. My app was sending it as `\\uXXXX` and Android was removing one backslash, so the text in Android app was displayed as `\uXXXX`. That's why I got moved to XML. 
This is the was I get the title from the XML text:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=" + movieUrl + "&format=xml");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String xml;
int startIndex, endIndex;
while ((xml = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (xml.contains("<title>")) {
        startIndex = xml.indexOf("<title>");
        endIndex = xml.indexOf("</title>");
        System.out.println(xml.substring(startIndex + 7, endIndex));
        return xml.substring(startIndex + 7, endIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no Gradle encoding, Intellij encoding, Java encoding: there simply is at least one text exchange in which the sender and the receiver don't use the same charset. You sould identify all such exchanges. For example, where do you see the wrong text? Is it standard cmd writte to with `System.out.pritln(String)`? What about the reading? Does your HTTP client use UTF-8 for decoding the YouTube response?

Comment: @Raffaele Generally, the output is sent as JSON object to the Android app. I can also send a query to the web application from my web browser. The problem is the same while quering via web browser. I did put `System.out.println(String)` and printed text is the same (I mean, it is correct while launching in IntelliJ and wrong while launching via Gradle in console). When I enter  http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvCtDwoCqGM&format=xml into Firefox, text is correctly displayed.

Comment: Again, without seeing the code one can't tell. Another inconsistency: Android apps are generally clients, so you can you *send* data to a client? Anyway, I guess there's an error in reading from YouTube. Please post the relevant code to see how you retrieve the data and store it in strings

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify which encoding the source has, so it defaults to `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` which varies as you have found out.
You can try both encodings; UTF-8 is my guess.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "Windows-1252"));
```

However UTF-8 could giver errors.

Ideal would be if the headers contain the charsets; dump them:

```
con.getContentType()
con.getHeaderFields()
```

Otherwise you can search the string for `<?xml ....>` and check whether a `encoding=...` is given. Regex:

```
Pattern encodingPattern =
    Pattern.compile("(?is)<\?xml[^>]*\\sencoding=['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"]");
Matcher m = encodingPattern.matcher(xml);
if (m.find()) {
    String encoding = m.group(1);
```

If that all gets too much, one might use an XML reader on an InputStream.

Comment: Your answer sounds interesting. Anyway, I launched my web app via gradle on another computer (with Ubuntu 14.04) and results were OK. But I'll try your solution to check whether my web app can be system-independent.

Comment: On Ubuntu the default encoding often is UTF-8.